# How do I represent line breaks in HTML within a string in Swift 3

Tags: html, ios, swift

I'm using the following code to extract weather information from the HTML of a website. The code tracks through the given URL and searches for content separated by the two phrases I've given as strings. The piece of information I need to extract is between two phrases but the first phrase has a line break in the HTML.

How do I represent this in the string? I've tried simply removing the line break and also using `\n` but this makes the fetch unsuccessful, as it can't find that phrase. I've represented the line break in my code as four asterisks.

I've also attached an image of the HTML I'm looking at. In this instance I'm trying to extract the time given in the HTML, but I also want to extract the 'Clear, cloudless sky' bit, which obviously will change regularly, as will some of the content preceding it.

The reason for needing the time is that I know this and the wind will change, and I want to ultimately extract the current conditions, so I'll have to tell the code to insert the correct time and wind to be able to fetch the current conditions.

```
if let url = attemptedURL {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let urlContent = data {
            let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            let websiteArray = webContent?.components(separatedBy: "<span class=\"current_description\">****<span>")

            if websiteArray!.count > 1 {
                let conditionArray = websiteArray![1].components(separatedBy: "</span>")

                if conditionArray.count > 1 {
                    self.wasConSuccessful = true

                    let extract = conditionArray[0].replacingOccurrences(of: "&deg;", with: "º")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                        print(extract)
                    })
                }
            }

            if self.wasConSuccessful == false {
                self.conditionsLabel.text = "!"
```

[image: Image of HTML]

Comment: Try representing the line break as `<br>`.

Comment: Nope - that didn't seem to do the trick.  Thanks for the suggestion, though

Comment: Try \r\n, that did it for me

Comment: No luck there - both with and without the indentation spaces.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: let text = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "<br>")
This did it for me,
self is the String because it is in a extension to get attributedString from String

Answer (score 2):

Using [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)

```
do{
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse("<span class=\"current_description\"><span>5:30</span><span>3 km/h</span></span>")
    let current_desc = try doc.getElementsByClass("current_description").first()
    try print(current_desc?.select("span").get(1).text())//"5:30"
}catch Exception.Error(let type, let message){
    print(message)
}catch{
    print("error")
}
```